# node.js / mongodb file structure

Tags: node.js, node-mongodb-native

I'm trying to set up this simnple NodeJS/mongodb app and I have my files structured like this:

```
server.js
    |
    +-routes/menu.js
    +-routes/cases.js
```

In my server.js I declare my mongodb vars like this:

```
var express = require('express'),
    mongo = require('mongodb'),
    Server = mongo.Server,
    MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient,
    Db = mongo.Db,
    http = require('http'),
    app = express(),
    httpServer = http.createServer(app),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    server = new Server('host.mongohq.com', 10066, {auto_reconnect : true}),
    db = new Db('myDb', server);

db.open(function(err, client) {
    client.authenticate('myUser', 'myPassword', function(err, success) {
        console.log('Authenticated');
    });
});
var cases = require('./routes/cases'),
    menu = require('./routes/menu');
```

But then when I try to reference my db var in eg menu.js like this:

```
db.collection(myCollection, function(err, collection) {});
```

I get an error that db is not defined.

Obviously I can move all the mongodb declarations down to both my menu.js and cases.js file but that's just very elegant. So how do I create one mongodb instance var and refer to it from my included files?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you require `server.js` in your `menu.js` file? Your `db` object isn't global. If you want it to be, declare it without `var`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to require `server.js` in your `menu.js` file.

Your `db` object isn't global. If you want it to be, declare it without `var`.